# Can a namespace be nested in a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

Can a `namespace` be nested in a class in C++?

Here is what I get with *gcc-11.2.0*:

```cpp
struct C1 {}; // works 
namespace N1 {const int a = 888;} // works

struct C2 { namespace N2 {const int a = 888;} };
// error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’
```

Namespaces can be nested, so why can't one nest a `namespace` in a class (which is also a kind of a `namespace`)?

Comment: Logically, it is because the standard requires a class to have exactly one declarative region (i.e. once a class definition is closed with the `}`, it can't be opened up and more members or type declarations added to it) but a namespace can have multiple declarative regions.   The difference is important for encapsulation using classes (e.g. once a class is defined, other code cannot come along and sneakily add new member functions to the class).  Placing a namespace in a class would break the requirement that it have only only one declarative region.